# Youtube-dl not downloading requested filesize

Tags: ffmpeg, cmd.exe, mp3, youtube-dl

So I currently have `"youtube-dl.exe" -l PL6NdkXsPL07IOu1AZ2Y2lGNYfjDStyT6O -f "[filesize<25M]" --audio-format "mp3" --ffmpeg-location "C:\Users\%Username%\Documents\youtube-dl\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"`
basically what I think my command does is targets a playlist to download and targets the videos that are less than 25 megabytes and formatting the videos to mp3 with ffmpeg file location in a certain directory. It just says 'requested format not available', but it should be able to take the video from 360p which should be just under 12mbs

Comment: So tldr: I just want to download songs with thte lowest file size (not format with ffmpeg, but downloading)

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1667932/1482432

Comment: I guess there's no way to actual limit the download size unless I use ffmpeg to format it after downloading huh. @Gantendo

Comment: with youtube-dlp  you can download the smallest size available. If you want to compress it even further you'll need extra software.

Comment: Thanks @Gantendo I dont think I'll be able to do anything else, guess I'll have to download the smallest size then use ffmpeg to compress it